# Python - How to create a folder with a user entered name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdir

I have a python script which runs to take screenshots in a loop and save all those images. However currently, all images are stored in Python35 folder.

Therefore I want the user to enter a name for a folder and create one by this name.

I know to use makedirs function and specify a path by `newpath=r'C:/users/../'` .

But how to append this new folder name specified by the user to the path?

(EDIT) Here is the Code I have:-

```
import openpyxl
import re
import os 
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
import webbrowser

source_excel=input('Enter the source excel file name-> ')
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(source_excel)
sheet=wb.active


strt=int(input('Enter starting range-> '))
end=int(input('Enter ending range-> '))

#NEED THE CHANGE HERE

foldname=input("Enter a folder name to create where images will be saved")
newpath=r'C:\Users\rnair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\'demofile 


# Loop to get the link from excel and take the screenshot by opening the browser for each link

for q in range(strt,end):
    getme=q,sheet.cell(row=q,column=1).value        #get link from excel file       
    ab=getme[1]
    #myopener=Myopen()
    rowc=str(strt)
    url=ab
    webbrowser.open(url)                            #opens browser for the link fetched

    time.sleep(7)                                   # Delay to wait for the page to load completely
    im=ImageGrab.grab()
    os.chdir(newpath)
    im.save("Row"+rowc+".jpg","JPEG")               # Saving image to file
    strt=strt+1
```

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html. Without seeing your actual code and proper problem statement it's hard to say more.

Comment: @Ro_nair A backslash in Python will escape a quote that follows it (among other things), so if you're working with Windows paths, use double slashes (which amount to a single escaped slash). That aside, your code as it is won't run, since the escaped quote in your assignment of `newpath` creates an unterminated string; fixing that alone wouldn't be sufficient, since you'd then have a syntax error immediately afterwards due to `demofile` being both undefined and not separated from your string by any operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean building the path at which the file should be saved, use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) with the base directory first and the custom directory name second (the filename can be provided as a third argument). Just be very careful about trusting user input for anything, *especially* filesystem manipulation.

Comment: @Ro_nair Aside from the problems mentioned in my comment on your original post: The usage for building your final path would be something like `os.path.join(basedir, foldname)`.

Comment: Thank You for a great explanation! I understood all and it worked as you said!